# How to rebuild optimized framework in Android

Tags: android, build, frameworks

Let assume that I want to add logs in [MediaHTTPConnection](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaHTTPConnection.java)

Couple weeks ago I was just doing:

```
make -j8 framework
```

And then framework.jar was created, which I could push on rooted device.

However now I see that boot.art and boot.oat are created and framework.jar is more or less "empty" and useless.
On the other hand I saw that I could build with:

```
DEXPREOPT_BOOT_JARS=false
```

and maybe it could fix my problem, however rebuilding whole project just to add some logs to framework doesn't look like smart idea ... So I would like to know if there is a way to somehow flash those new boot.art and boot.oat?

**EDIT:**

As stated above for now my workaround is rebuilding whole Android with flags that prevents dex optimization. Then I have normal framework.jar (couple MB instead of couple KB) which I can replace with framework build with the same flags. It's not so terrible (since I build whole project once) but still I would like to know better solution for that. Although I doubt it currently exists.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more details of how you build framework.jar and how you use it with ART?

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following:

mmm frameworks/base
adb remount
adb shell stop
adb sync
adb shell start

additional resources can be found here:
http://devtcg.blogspot.in/2009/03/building-running-and-debugging-android.html

Comment: Link you're sharing is from 2009 while I think odexing is more "fresh" topic (at least odexing Android framework).

Answer (score 0):

If ADB remount won't work:

```
# Script to mount Android Device as read/write.
# List the Devices.
adb devices;

# Run adb as root (Needs root access).
adb root;

# Since you're running as root su is not required
adb shell mount -o rw,remount /;

adb sync
adb shell start
```